# Auth0 Request and use a Management API token from a Flutter App

Tags: flutter, jwt, access-token, auth0, pkce

We need to allow our Flutter application to save a property in the user_metadata when the application starts.
As I understand this is a task to be done with the Management API and in order for the Flutter application to be able to write in the user_metadata the client has to request a Management API access token.

I found no information on how to request this token, the closest thing is this page in the documentation that has no example and no explanation on how to retrieve this token:
https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/access-tokens/get-management-api-tokens-for-single-page-applications

Can anyone provide an example on how to request this token from a Flutter app?
Even a generic CURL request would be helpful to understand what endpoint to call with which parameters.

Error received when trying to access the Management API to update the user_metadata:

```
body{
 "statusCode":400,
 "error":"Bad Request",
 "message":"Bad HTTP authentication header format",
 "errorCode":"Bearer"
}
```

Comment: It seems you just do a normal SPA PKCE flow, but request some unusual scopes? `Authenticate the user by redirecting them to the Authorization endpoint, which is where users are directed upon login or sign-up.` seems to indicate a normal PKCE flow, and just above that is a table of scopes, e.g. `update:current_user_metadata`

Comment: @RichardHeap I just added the error I get back when trying the update request from the app. I set up 2 Auth0 application, one `native` for the main application and one `machine-to-machine` that I thought was needed to get the proper access token. (first app has `read:user_app_metadata` `update:user_app_metadata` `create:user_app_metadata` and the second has: `read:current_user` `create:current_user_metadata` `create:current_user_metadata`)

Comment: Are you substituting the right values in the second step shown? Does the decoded JWT you get back from the auth endpoint have the right scopes? And have you practiced the mgmt api requests with one of the test bearer tokens you seem to be able to generate (see previous page of tutorial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 steps are needed:

1. Get the authentication [token for management API](https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/access-tokens/management-api-access-tokens):

sample curl:

```
curl --location --request POST "https://YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN/oauth/token" \
--header "content-type: application/json" \
--data-raw "{
    \"grant_type\": \"client_credentials\",
    \"audience\": \"https://YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN/api/v2/\",
    \"client_id\": \"YOUR_AUTH0_APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID\",
    \"client_secret\": \"YOUR_AUTH0_APPLICATION_CLIENT_SECRET\"
}"
```

2. call the [management api to update app_metadata](https://auth0.com/docs/manage-users/user-accounts/metadata/manage-metadata-api)

sample curl:

```
curl --request PATCH \
  --url 'https://YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN/api/v2/users/USER_ID' \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer TOKEN_FROM_STEP_1' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{"email": "whatever@example.com", "user_metadata": {"hobby": "surfing"}, "app_metadata": {"plan": "full"}}'
```

Edit: Patch request with userID

Comment: The user id is not needed in the second request?

Comment: the docs suggest only email, so that should work

Comment: Your answer was useful however the POST did not work for me, I had to use a PATCH with the user ID.

Comment: If you update also with the PATCH request I will consider it the right answer :)

Comment: Thanks for that, now the answer is more useful for anyone who needs help :)